# amazon ecs Container for Configuration files

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

at the moment I try to figure out a good setup for my application in amazon ecs.

My application needs a config file. Now I want to have a container to hold my config file so when I want to change something I don't need to redeploy my application.

I can't find any best practice method for this. What I found out is that the ecs tasks just make a `docker run` and you can't make a `docker create`.

Does anyone have an idea how I can manage my config files for my applications?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely using Docker for this is overkill. How complex is the data? If it's simple key-value pairs I would use DynamoDB and get rid of the file completely. Another option would be using EFS for the file, or attaching/detaching an EBS volume.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do that, it makes it fragile and you're not guaranteed to be able to access it from all containers across a cluster (or you end up having that on all instances which wastes resources). Why not package it up with the container as-is or package it as much as possible and provide environment variables to fill in the gap? If you really want to go this route I highly suggest something like S3